# Copy and Paste in Last Non Blank Cell in a different Column

Tags: vba, excel

How to copy from A10 until last non blank cell in Column G?
I saw some other answers with "Dim" but did not work for me.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPYcF.png)

Here is the code I'm trying to make work.

```
Sub SelectLastRange()
'
' SelectLastRange Macro
'

'

lMaxRows = Sheets("PEDIDOS").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("DATABASE").Range("A10:G").End(xlDown).Copy: Sheets("DESTINATION").Range("B" & lMaxRows + 1).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues): Application.CutCopyMode = False

    End Sub
```

Comment: Can you clarify you're question please. Where do you want to copy the range A10:G to?

What happens if there is a column that has more rows than G, do you want the range to be extended further?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

```
Sub CopyPaste()
Dim lastused As Long
Dim lastempty As Long

lastused = Sheets("DATABASE").Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastempty = Sheets("PEDIDOS").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

Sheets("DATABASE").Range("A10:G" & lastused).copy
Sheets("PEDIDOS").Range("B" & lastempty).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```